# How can I use standard sklearn components for adaptive Lasso?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

How can I use standard sklearn components for adaptive Lasso?

Here is an attemp using LinearRegression to get first weights, then I try to apply them to the Lasso by multplying the X matrix - is this the correct approach?

Also, I get 'inf's in my weights - how should that be handled?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso, LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets

# Generate dataset
number_observations = 100
number_variables = 200
number_significant_variables = 10

x, y, true_beta = sklearn.datasets.make_regression(
  n_samples=number_observations, n_features=number_variables,
  n_informative=number_significant_variables, n_targets=1,
  bias=10.0, noise=1.0, shuffle=True, coef=True, random_state=1)

X = pd.DataFrame(data = x, columns=[f'F{x}' for x in range(number_variables)])
y = pd.DataFrame(data = y, columns=['P0'])
X = X / X.std()
y = y / y.std()

ols = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False,positive=True).fit(X,y)
weights = [1/np.power(np.abs(x),1) for x in ols.coef_]

X_w = X * weights

lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.02,fit_intercept=False,positive=True,max_iter=1000)
lasso.fit(X_w,y)
```